# Edit CustomXML with OpenXML C#

Tags: c#, openxml, docx

This is my first OpenXML project.  I am trying to edit the CustomXML file of a docx file.  I am trying to change this:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <PERSON>
          <NAMETAG>NAME</NAMETAG>
          <DOBTAG>DOB</DOBTAG>
          <SCORE1TAG>SCORE1</SCORE1TAG>
          <SCORE2TAG>SCORE2</SCORE2TAG>
      </PERSON>
```

To this:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <PERSON>
          <NAMETAG>John Doe</NAMETAG>
          <DOBTAG>01/01/2020</DOBTAG>
          <SCORE1TAG>90.5</SCORE1TAG>
          <SCORE2TAG>100.0</SCORE2TAG>
      </PERSON>
```

I would prefer to not use search and replace but instead navigate the WordprocessingDocument to find the correct properties to modify.  I tried to do a whole delete/add but that corrupted the file and did not work.  Here is that code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Simple_Template.docx");

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
                WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true);

                doc.MainDocumentPart.DeleteParts<CustomXmlPart>(doc.MainDocumentPart.CustomXmlParts);

                string newcustomXML = @"<?xml version=""1.0\"" encoding=""UTF-8\""?><Person><NAMETAG>John Doe</NAMETAG><DOBTAG>DOB</DOBTAG><SCORE1TAG>90.5</SCORE1TAG><SCORE2TAG>100.0</SCORE2TAG></PERSON>";

                CustomXmlPart xmlPart = doc.MainDocumentPart.AddCustomXmlPart(CustomXmlPartType.CustomXml);
                byte[] byteArrayXML = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newcustomXML);
                using (MemoryStream xml_strm = new MemoryStream(byteArrayXML))
                {
                    xmlPart.FeedData(xml_strm);
                }


                doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
                doc.Close();

                File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Simple_Template_Replace.docx", stream.ToArray());
            }
        }
```

I have also tried to navigate through the structure but I am having a hard time figuring out where in the WordprocessingDocument object contains the actual values that I need to modify.  Ideally, I would like something like this psuedo-code:

```
doc.MainDocumentPart.CustomXMLPart.Select("NAMETAG") = "John Doe"
```

--------Follow On----------

The answer below worked well without a Namespace.  Now I would like to add one.  This is the new XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><myxml xmlns="www.mydomain.com">
<PERSON>
  <NAMETAG>NAME</NAMETAG>
  <DOBTAG>DOB</DOBTAG>
  <SCORE1TAG>SCORE1</SCORE1TAG>
  <SCORE2TAG>SCORE2</SCORE2TAG>
</PERSON>
</myxml>
```

I have adjusted the code to the following but the SelectSingleNode call is returning NULL.  Here is the updated code:

```
                    XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);
                    mgr.AddNamespace("ns", "www.mydomain.com");

                    string name_tag = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/ns:myxml/ns:PERSON/ns:NAMETAG", mgr).InnerText;
```

I was able to fix this myself.  I did not realize that you need to include "ns:" with every element.  I still thought that I would be able to pass in String.Empty into my AddNamespace and then I would not have to do it.  But this will work for now.

Comment: Does your word document have this xml inside it?

Comment: Yes, it does.  I used the XML Mapping Pane to add it and verified it was there, by unzipping the project and viewing the customxml folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `newcustomXML` value, it has two '\' characters in the XML declaration and also the start tag of "PERSON" element has capital case instead of upper case.

So, try using the following instead:

```
string newcustomXML = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<PERSON>
    <NAMETAG>John Doe</NAMETAG>
    <DOBTAG>01/01/2020</DOBTAG>
    <SCORE1TAG>90.5</SCORE1TAG>
    <SCORE2TAG>100.0</SCORE2TAG>
</PERSON>";
```

Also regarding your navigation attempt, try using this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

    byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Simple_Template.docx");
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
        WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true);

        CustomXmlPart xmlPart = doc.MainDocumentPart.CustomXmlParts.First();
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

        using (var inputStream = xmlPart.GetStream(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            xmlDocument.Load(inputStream);
            xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/PERSON/NAMETAG").InnerText = "John Doe";

            xmlDocument.Save(outputStream);
            outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            xmlPart.FeedData(outputStream);
        }

        doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
        doc.Close();

        File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Simple_Template_Replace.docx", stream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error on the xmlPart.FeedData(outputStream) line:

System.IO.Compression: Entries cannot be opened multiple times in Update mode.  Do you get the same error?

Comment: @JeremyH I'm not reproducing this, what changes have you made? Can you post your new snippet code?

Comment: I have added a new question here.  Any help you can provide is appreciated.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/63381348/14028831